# How to execute an test in a ansible raw module statement?

Tags: linux, command-line, ansible

I am running the raw module of ansible ***using non-root user*** and want to give a command that checks some condition. For example I want to check whether a directory exists or not before deleting it. Like the following command.

```
[ -d "$DIR" ] && echo "Yes"
```

Now I want to give the non-root user permission to run this command in the sudoers file.

```
xyzUser ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: 'something/that/lets/me/run/that/command'
```

So, I want to know what I can write in the sudoers that will let me run this command and all other condition based commands.

Comment: You should be able to run echo and test without any special permissions?

Comment: so i ran this -- test -d "/etc" && echo "Exists"   command in the raw module without adding any special permissions in the sudoers file. But the ansible script gets stuck and does't execute.

Comment: If you just want to check whenever a file or directory exists why not do it [the ansible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654286/how-check-a-file-exists-in-ansible)? As per [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/raw_module.html) the raw module should rarely be used. It's unclear where your script get stuck or what error you might be seeing or why you suspect it to be the sudoers file in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by "all other condition based commands"? Every command sets an exit code and could thus potentially be used in a condition.

Comment: @Seth I am running the scripts using a non-root user. To do that you need to give that user all the permissions a root user has, and of course i can't do that. So, its workaround is to use raw module and give user permissions to only execute those commands. For more info - [link](https://gist.github.com/nanobeep/3b3d614a709086ff832a).

Comment: It sounds like you just shouldn't be using ansible because it doesn't match what your requirements are. Go and look for a different solution instead of messing up your system AND writing bad ansible scripts. Your link already contains a non-sudo approach which is way more sane than what you're currently trying to do. Even if you are running it as a non root user `test` and `echo` don't require any special privileges unless you strictly limited that account.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, that's true. So, what I want to know is how to give those commands so that I don't need to give any extra permissions or if any extra permission is required then how to give that too.

Comment: If that was meant to clarify something, I'm afraid it failed monumentally.

Comment: @Seth there are already hundreds of written scripts that are running the ansible scripts using root user. I am just modifying so that it supports non root user also. If you have any other idea please share.

Comment: What you are looking for is nonsense. You want to be as generic as possible and you're **not** looking for a solution for a specific problem. Either make the non-root user a root user or just grant him everything in sudo (same result). In addition you're missing something while debugging. Because (as mentioned before) `test` and `echo` are not restricted by default. So either you didn't explain your setup properly or you fail on properly debugging what is going on. If you want to make sure just add entries for `test` and `echo`. You haven't even included your ansible script in your question.

Comment: @Seth Really? What is nonsense? I already told you this is supposed to be a non-root user running the scripts. And if I could grant non-root user every privilege then I wouldn't be here. And i just have 1 task in the script, the one i posted above, inside the raw module(Though i am open to suggestions if there are any better commands out there).

Comment: Take a different approach. The raw module is a bad fit for what you want to do. One is described in the link your provided yourself.  As mentioned (again) `echo` and `test` are not limited. If you do think they are include both in your sudoers file. The issue is probably something else like insufficient/wrong escapes, [your ansible version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) or something else. You still haven't expanded on any of the information that's missing from your question. It's an ansible issue you're trying to solve and not a sudo issue.

Answer (score 0):

> For example I want to check whether a directory exists or not before deleting it.

```
- name: Example playbook to make sure a dir is absent
  hosts: my_host_group
  # Connect with a non-root user
  remote_user: my_remote_user
  # Use sudo, as you say you need it. Configure it on the relevant host
  become: true 

  vars:
    dir_to_remove: /path/to/dir/on/host

  tasks:
    - name: "remove {{ dir_to_remove }} if exists. Do nothing otherwise"
      file:
        path: "{{ dir_to_remove }}"
        state: absent
```